# How to define your own Map in Java

Tags: java

I have to write a program who use collection for implementing a map in Java.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Maps don't have a concept of an owner. What high level need are you trying to solve and how does this relate to your map?

Comment: From the wording, I think the high level need is "homework."

Comment: Do you mean "How to write my own implementation of the `Map` interface"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a type MapEntry that holds a key and a value.

Take some collection class and extend it with methods `put(Object key, Object value)`, `get(Object key)`, `remove(Object key)` and `containsKey(Object key)`. Parametrize it to be a collection of MapEntries.

First, **containsKey**: Loop through your collection, looking for a MapEntry that has a key value corresponding to the given key. Return true if you found one, false otherwise.

Next, **put**: Loop through your collection, looking for a MapEntry with the same key. If you find one, replace the value. If not, create a new MapEntry with the key and value and add it to your collection.

**get**: Loop through your collection, looking for a MapEntry with the given key. If you find one, return the value, otherwise null.

**remove**: Loop through... if you find one, remove that map entry.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

So, You want to write a program that uses `Map`, you can seek it from [Oracle Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html). Next time, try to be specific and and clear on your question, so as to get better answers...

Comment: The text of the question wasn't very eloquent, but I think you completely misunderstood it.